# Improve the performance of an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

How to improve the performance of an ASP.NET application? Which are are the fields I should take care? The application includes DB connections and Image Parsing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book [Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998530.aspx) has a chapter on [Improving ASP.NET Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx), that might be worth reading. The full book is online at MSDN, and is also available as a [PDF download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8A2E454D-F30E-4E72-B531-75384A0F1C47&displaylang=en).

Comment: any updates for 2020  ? Now, ASP.NET MVC 5, ASP.NET CORE, and BLAZOR.

Answer (score 4):

[10 Tips for Writing High-Performance Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx)

[20 Tips to Improve ASP.net Application Performance](http://www.realsoftwaredevelopment.com/20-tips-to-improve-aspnet-application-performance/)

Bye

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a book about this that was just released, called [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET: Build Ultra-Fast and Ultra-Scalable web sites using ASP.NET and SQL Server](http://tinyurl.com/89lf5xm).

The book is about 500 pages long, so there's a fair amount you can do, at all tiers: client (HTML/JavaScript structure), IIS, ASP.NET, SQL Server, infrastructure, etc.

Answer (score 2):

try avoiding unnecessary postbacks to pages, there are a lot of features you can implement by using things like jQuery or ExtJs framework. Learn how to do AJAX calls and pass info between your app and the server via JSON result sets.

Also, install apps like FireBug and YSlow and use these to analyze your application and follow their recommendations on how to speed up your app. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1. HTTP Compression
2. Disable Possible ViewState
3. Changes in the Web.Config File : 
   Use page caching, 
   Remove unnecessary httpModules, 
   Turn off trace, 
   Disabled automatic save for profiles, 
   Set debug=false.
4. Implement Cache Dependency
5. Optimize Stylesheets
6. Optimize JavaScript
7. JS and CSS File Position
8. server.transfer() Instead of response.redirect()
9. Client-side Script for Validation

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excerpt from the book Jeff, Phil, and K. Scott Allen wrote:
[8 ASP.NET Performance Tips](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/aspnet-performance-tips/). It's a few years old, but most of it's pretty timeless.

My checklist:

1. Find out what's slow by testing
2. Cache what you can (application cache, output cache, etc.)
3. Reduce page size (eliminate viewstate, compress images, use CSS instead of inline styles, etc.)
4. Find out which external dependencies are slowing you down (worst queries, webservices, etc.).
5. Offload processing to the client (jQuery for filtering vs. round trips to the server to server to re-query)

Answer (score 0):

Use the .NET CLR profiler to determine where optimization will be useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301839.aspx

Comment: quite useless for web projects