# improving performance of the web application by avoiding asp.net components and using only html components

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have heard that html components are light weight than asp.net components, so will the performance of the web application increase by avoiding the usage of asp.net components like asp:button and use only html components ??

Also will the usage of asp.net components increase server load??
when an event occurs (say asp.net button click) will the entire view state be sent across to the server and received back? so this will be causing lot of data to be transmitted to and fro right?

These will not happen if i use html buttons and ajax calls to send/receive data instead of asp.net elements and thus performance will be optimized. is my understanding correct? please provide your view

Answer (score 2):

If you use html elements instead of asp.net elements it is true that the size of the ViewState will re reduced but I am not sure that this will optimize your web application, since you will have to write extra code to handle input from the HTML elements. You will have to write more complicated code and this code will add some overhead on your application's performance.

In every event (e.g. `Button_Click`) the entire ViewState is sent to the web server. Having a large ViewState will make your application slow and heavy.

Using ajax calls is a good approach since this way you make small requests that do one action and because of that they are usually lightweight. Also, using ajax calls also gives a richer user experience.

My opinion in general is:

- Don't use plain html elements instead of ASP.NET elements. You can use html elements in cases where they will not be used in the code behind (so they wont be included in the ViewState).
- You can disable the ViewState in user controls of your applications if it not required. This way, using ASP.NET elements will not increase your ViewState.
- Start using cache in your system. You can cache .aspx pages or .ascx controls using the `Output` directive, or you can use the ASP.NET cache mechanism (`HttpContext.Current.Cache`) and put objects there. This way, you can reduce the number of calls in the database.
- Prefer using ajax over full postbacks when possible. Prefer to use jQuery to make ajax calls insead of using UpdatePanels, which they make a full postback so they are not very light weight.

I would also recommend to learn how ViewState works so that you can find ways to reduce its size.

I just found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151789/improve-the-performance-of-an-asp-net-application) in which ASP.NET performance is discussed in general, you might find it useful.

Comment: Thank you, I am planning to use handlers instead of web methods and code behind, so i think html components will be better